# Change listener is not firing when adding new object from the native module

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native, realm

I'm trying to use realm as a middleman in a react-native project to communicate between native module (Android-Java) and react-native. But the change listener is not firing in js side when i add new object from native module.

**Expected Results**

The change listener in js should fire when i add a new object to the realm. And also the change listener in android (java) should fire when i add a new object to the realm from js side

**Actual Results**

When i add an object from java the change listener in java is firing. And when i add an object from js the change listener in js is also firing. But when i try to add an object from js the change listener in java is not firing.

**Steps to Reproduce**

Note: When i mean both side i mean javascript and java

Open a realm in both side
Write a query in both side. For example get all users.
Add change listener to that collection in both side.
Add new object from the javascript
The change listener in javascript will fire but the change listener in java will not.

**Code Sample**

I shared an example code in the repo below
https://github.com/muraterd/Realm1/

**Version of Realm and Tooling**

Realm JS SDK Version: 2.18.0

Comment: How are you opening the realm (new realm, or realm.open)? Are you using the chrome debugger? If you are using new realm have you checked you are actually connected? I opened a github issue about the listeners behaving weirdly when you are debugging a synced realm using 'new realm'. Does it work whech using realm.open and no debug?

Comment: I'm using Realm.open() on js side. You can see my code example here https://github.com/muraterd/Realm1/